# How to run a JavaScript file from shell?

Tags: javascript

Can I run a JavaScript file from shell (Window\Linux) ?

I just want to show a message box to the user and based on the button selected perform some action. The buttons also need to be customized.

Comment: Message Box? Button? How are those going to be generated in a shell? I think you'd need to script a browser for that.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you could use [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host).

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful ?

[Interpret and execute arbitrary Javascript in Linux CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957375/interpret-and-execute-arbitrary-javascript-in-linux-cli)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at HTA apps for Windows. It's basically a windows application written in HTML and JS.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx